# Downgrade from Windows 11 Pro oem to Windows 10 ltsc?

Tags: windows-10, window, downgrade

Is this possible?
I heard that a downgrade to the corresponding Windows 10 version is okay (e.g. pro -> pro)

How does this work with ltsc?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 **Enterprise** LTSC is not the Pro version, so you cannot install
it when the currently installed version is Windows 11 **Pro**.

If your computer had Windows 10 and you upgraded to Windows 11,
you should rollback immediately if that is your wish.
You only have 10 days for rolling back.

Answer (score 0):

If the manufacturer of the computer did not provide downgrade rights to your OEM license (so a Windows 10 license), then you will have to procure a Windows 10 license and install it yourself.

Now you said you wanted LTSC and there is no way to downgraded that way. You must reinstall.

Note:  Windows 11 can be made to work very closely to Windows 10, so you may be better off to adapt to Windows 11. I am using Windows 11 Pro.

Comment: If you're running LTSC you need a volume install don't ya?